# In a function associated with an API call: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, typeerror

I'm working with the movie DB API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list this one)
and I print with VUE the results of my call in my page.
The API provides me all data I need to have to achieve my goal, that is this
[image: Screen of my work]

As you can see, under the show name there are the genres associated with that name.
Let's take for example the object I obtain when the API gives me A-Team

```
"backdrop_path": "/ggPjnOA5sap6wyuAGUY7kwRseEi.jpg",
            "first_air_date": "1983-01-23",
            "genre_ids": [
                10759
            ],
            "id": 1516,
            "media_type": "tv",
            "name": "A-Team",
            "origin_country": [
                "US"
            ],
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_name": "The A-Team",
            "overview": "Un commando di ex-combattenti della guerra del Vietnam chiamato A-Team (Squadra A), un tempo appartenenti ai corpi speciali dell'esercito degli Stati Uniti, viene accusato ingiustamente di aver rapinato la banca di Hanoi. Evasi in maniera rocambolesca, vivono ora in fuga, ricercati e braccati dalle autorità per un reato che non hanno mai commesso. I componenti della squadra sopravvivono prestando servizio come mercenari e venendo, nella quasi totalità degli episodi, assoldati da varie persone o gruppi di persone che vivono oppresse da situazioni d'ingiustizia nei propri confronti. Grazie alle qualità militari e umane dell'A-Team, ogni episodio si risolve in maniera definitiva a favore dei più deboli. Pur essendo visti come mercenari dagli altri personaggi della serie, i membri dell'A-Team sono dunque schierati sempre dalla parte del bene. Famoso è il loro furgone GMC Vandura nero e grigio con 2 strisce rosse laterali che si uniscono sullo spoiler superiore, usato come mezzo principale di trasporto dell'A-Team.",
            "popularity": 141.786,
            "poster_path": "/iJsueZM8TqQzeB55tol4mnyQzb9.jpg",
            "vote_average": 7.4,
            "vote_count": 574
        },
```

As you can see there's a sub-array called `genre_ids` that contains the id of the associated genre for this specific show. To obtain the name, I've used another call of the API that provides me an array of objects where every object has two properties, the id of a genre and the name of a genre. So, from this array you can easily obtain the associated genre name for a show and print it.
I did this operation in this way, doing `.map` on the array obtained from the shows'API call:

`searchShow()` is a function that starts when you press enter in the `input` that you can see in the picture above, `this.userSearch` is in fact the `v-model` associated with that `input`.

```
searchShow() {
            axios
                // this is the call that provides me an array of object like the A-Team's one seen before
                .get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi`, {
                params: {
                            api_key: this.apiKey,
                            query: this.userSearch,
                            language: this.userLanguage,
                        },
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    const result = response.data.results;
                    // I save result in an empty array created in data 
                    this.searchResults = result;

                    // I insert a new property inside the array obtained right now,
                    // this property provides me genres name
                    
                    const newArray = this.searchResults.map ((element) => {
                        let objectResults = element.genre_ids;
                        let object = element;
                        // object.genres_name it's an empty array where I save in my results
                        object.genres_name = [];
                        // this.genresList it's the array in which I've saved the API call that gives me objects with ids and genres's name
                            this.genresList.forEach(genre => {
                            // ids of genres are the same everywhere. If the ones in the 
                            // genresList array are included in each element.genre_ids
                            // then push the name as an object, so it's printable in HTML
                            if (objectResults.includes(genre.id)) {
                                object.genres_name.push(
                                    {
                                        genre: genre.name
                                    
                                    }    
                                    );
                                }
                            })
                            
                    // return the element updated
                    return object;
                    })
                    // this.arrayProva is now equal to the map of the original array and it's
                    // the array printed in HTML
                    this.arrayProva = newArray;
                });
        },
```

And with this I can print easily the genres' names in HTML because I've added a new property leaning on an existing one. The problem comes when a show doesn't have associated any genre, maybe a not-so-famous show, but it brokes my project since the error appears and vue doesn't print anymore the search results.
This happens because a single element doesn't have the sub-array genre-ids that I use to add genres' names to any single show.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you simply need to deal with the case where `element.genre_ids` is not defined in the API result, I think you could simply change the assignment of `objectResults` to be:

```
let objectResults = element.genre_ids || [];
```

This will supply a default empty array in the event the one obtained from the API is null or not defined.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know you could declare a variable in that way